# Examples of arbitrary groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is an arbitrary group with order $m$ and $n$ divides $m$, then $G$ need not have a cyclic subgroup of order $n$. Find two such examples, one where $n=m$ and another where $n<m$.

---

Should I be looking at certain types of groups here? I've looked at $U(\mathbb{Z}_{13})$ and didn't have any luck, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: For an example with $n=m$, just take any group that is not cyclic. $U(13)$ is a bad choice, because it is cyclic. I would suggest looking at direct products of cyclic groups.

Comment: Do you think $D_3$ would work? (the symmetries of a triangle)

Comment: For the $n = m$ case, yes. For the other cases, no (you should really just try and see for yourself).

Comment: I think I might not be understanding the question quite right. In $D_3$, $\rho$ has order 3 since $\rho^3=e$, but there are other cyclic subgroups of $D_3$ which also have elements of order 3.

Comment: You are asked to find an example of a group $G$ of order $n$ and a divisor $m$ of $n$ such that $G$ has no cyclic subgroup of order $m$, both in the case where $m = n$ and where $m < n$.

Comment: I don't see how $D_3$ would work then for the $m=n$ case.

Comment: Do you understand that for the n=m case, all the question is asking you to do is find any group at all that is not cyclic?

Comment: @TheMobiusLoop The order of $D_3$ is $m=6$. Can you find a *cyclic* subgroup of order $n=6$?

Comment: I had misunderstood what the order of $G$ was. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=S_4$, the symmetry group of degree 4. Then $m=|G|=24$. But $G$ does not have any elements of order $n=12$. This is the example for $n <m$. The group for $n=m$ is easy to find, for example, $S_3$.

Comment: In general, a solution to the $n<m$ case is also a solution to the $n=m$ case.